# Для заданной страницы сервер возвращает 500 (Яндекс)

Tags: .htaccess, яндекс-поиск

Пытаюсь добавить сайт в http://webmaster.yandex.ru/addurl.xml и в ответ мне такое:

> Для заданной страницы (или страницы, полученной после перенаправления) сервер возвращает код статуса http 500 (ожидался код 200).

Сам сайт доступен, а вот Яндекс говорит, что недоступен.

В htaccess пользуюсь так:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteRule ^ref([0-9]+)$ /?ref=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Руками что отдается 200 или 500?
Веб-консоль браузера (опера, хром) может помочь вам это увидеть.

Если 500, попробуйте закомментировать DirectoryIndex. Скорее всего на хостинге запрещена именно эта директива (500 ошибка бывает в том числе, когда в htaccess'e бывает то, что нельзя).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В помощи к htaccess порядок таков:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^ref([0-9]+)$ /?ref=$1 [L]
```

Может из-за этого не работает?